# HTML best practice to animate and fallback

Tags: jquery, animation

I have to do some animations in a homepage like Apple's iPhone homepage

http://www.apple.com/iphone/

Mine are quite simpler, just some left to right slide in (with fade in) for a div, stay a few seconds, slide out and the same effect to the following div.

I'm planning to use jQuery's .animate() since I'm using jQuery for almost everything else in the site but I have some doubts:

1. Is jQuery the best way to animate objects? I also considered using CSS3 transitions but I suspect jQuery is more compatible with not so modern browsers (IE cough... cough...)
2. What would be the event to fire the animation? How can I be sure the image in the div is loaded before animating it?
3. The initial state for the elements would be 0% opacity si I can then animate them to 100%. If someone has javascript turned off or there's any error in the page and the animation function doesn't run, the elements would stay invisible to them. Having the initial state 100% opacity and then change it to 0% to animate it would make a blink if the turning it to 0% by code doesn't run before the element is displayed. Can I prevent this?
4. Whats is the best way to time the animation? Having a $(element).delay(N), N being the time it takes for the previous elements to go in, show and go out doesn't seem right.

I know all this might probably be covered somewhere else. If there's a good article or tutorial on how to achieve this just point me to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Building a custom slider takes more time than what it seems at first. I would suggest to go for a plugin like [nivoslider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) or any other jQuery slider out there. You can choose your transition and duration to acheive the desired effect.

If you really want to build from scratch, i would definitely go for jQuery.

1. You are right about compatibility, jQuery is better then CSS3 on that regard.
2. I would go for a javascript interval. Have a look here : [Simple image load](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simple-image-load-detection-with-load)
3. If the user has javascript turned off, your slide won't even animate. To prevent the blink, you should change the opacity before you start the animation.

You should have a look at the [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)  docs for more info

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to achieve a [jQuery slideshow](https://www.google.se/search?q=jquery+slideshow). I haven't tried it myself, but the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) seems to be able to do what you want.

In addition, to solve the blink/no javascript support problem, you could add something like this to the `head` section of your document:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
    .hidden { visible: true; !important }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to do a slideshow. different elements would be animated separately, there would be no next/previous button nor a number of slides indicator. in a given time 3 elements would be animated at the same time, which would require 3 instances of a slider. I use nivo slider a lot but I don't think its the best solution for this